# Google Oauth - access_token is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

After trying to use libraries, I am trying to implement Google OAuth login myself.

I have created app on google and I'm trying to login with code:

View:

```
<a href="#" class="button"  id="A1" onclick="OpenGoogleLoginPopup();" name="butrequest"> <span>Login with google</span></a>
...
<script type="text/javascript" language=javascript>
    function OpenGoogleLoginPopup() {
        var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?";
        url += "scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&";
        url += "state=%2Fprofile&"
        url += "redirect_uri=<%=Return_url %>&"
        url += "response_type=token&"
        url += "client_id=<%=Client_ID %>";

        window.location = url;
    }
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            Client_ID = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["google_clientId"].ToString();
            Return_url = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["google_RedirectUrl"].ToString();
        }
        if (Request.QueryString["access_token"] != null)
        {
            String URI = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + Request.QueryString["access_token"].ToString();
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(URI);
            string  b;
            using (StreamReader br = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                b = br.ReadToEnd();
            }
...
```

But after I login to google and redirect to this page from google `Request.QueryString["access_token"]` is null.

What did I do wrong now? I use data marked with blue arrow from google console:

[image]

Comment: http://www.wenda.io/questions/4801898/google-oauth-access-token-is-always-null.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access_token is not returned to you on the first redirect back from Google.

OAuth2 works like this:

1. You send the user to the login url, passing your clientID, redirect_uri, and state  (you did this)
2. After the user logs in successfully, google redirects a GET request back to the redirect_uri and passes you the state that you sent and an access code.
3. In that GET request to your server, you must then POST back to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token  and send them your client_secret along with the code that they passed to you.
4. The response of that post will contain the access_token you are looking for.

I suggest you read through https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#authenticatingtheuser